# General Relativity via light cones curvature?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, metric-tensor, curvature, causality

Is it possible to reformulate general relativity as curvature of objects' light cones instead of curvature of spacetime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lightcone structure (usually referred to as the causal structure) is not enough to determine the spacetime. The causal structure corresponds to nearly all degrees of freedom of the gravitational field, but the "conformal degree of freedom". That is a different way of saying that two spacetimes have the same causal structure if, and only if, their metrics are related by
$$ g_{ab} = \Omega^2 g'_{ab}$$
for some function $\Omega$. This is discussed, for example, in Wald's book (check Chap. 8 and App. D, it is probably in one of these).

Notice that this implies, for example, that there are spacetimes with the same lightcone structure of Minkowski spacetime, but which are not flat. They are called conformally flat.

Hence, just specifying how the lightcones behave is not enough. You still miss some information that the metric would need to give you. I am not aware of any ways of encoding this as an extra information to the causal structure.

Comment: Thank you for answering! Does that degree of freedom really matter, though? If we move all curvature into the casual structure, wouldn't it make the spacetime flat?

Comment: In other words, postulate gamma = 1?

Comment: @Chedim it does matter because conformally equivalent doesn't lead to equivalent dynamics (e.g. geodesics & trajectories). For example, FLRW cosmology is conformally flat but clearly not physically equivalent.