# Same curvature but different orientation of light cones?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, curvature, causality

Can there be two regions of spacetime which have the same curvature, but with their light cones oriented in different directions?

In the Stack Exchange question "[General Relativity via light cones curvature?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/720690/general-relativity-via-light-cones-curvature)", we learn that two spacetimes with the same light cone structure are not necessarily the same/do not necessarily have the same curvature. But this is the opposite question: can two spacetimes with the same curvature have different light cone structures?

I am a newbie to General Relativity, and have been reading some textbooks on GR and Black Holes. The motivation for my question comes from the fact that inside a black hole, we know the light cones are tilted horizontally, such that time becomes space and space becomes time. But I cannot visualize what curved spacetime must look like in order for the light cones to be tilted horizontally instead of vertically.

Here is one picture of a curved 2D-manifold with light cones from Brian Cox's book "Black Holes". There seems to be a relationship between how the light cones are oriented, and how spacetime is curved:

[image]

There is also the popular image showing how a massive object (star, black hole) causes light cones to tilt towards them:

[image]

But my question is, is Curvature of spacetime the sole reason for the way the light cones tilt the way they do? Can we have two regions of spacetime which curve the same way, but have light cones aligned in opposite/different directions than each other?